# Dynamically adding elements with jquery error

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, json

Here is my fiddle : [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/jomo7my4/)

According to data JSON, there are 2 "groups". 
Each group has 2 "widgets" each.
Every widget has certain "controls"

Light/Brightness/Color controls can be there for Philips widget. They are associated with a switch/slider/color picker respectively.

```
  for (var k = 0; k < data.groups[i].widgets[j].controls.length; k++) {

    $("." + data.groups[i].name + " > .widgets-container > ." + data.groups[i].widgets[j].name + " > .widget-header > .widget-label > .row > .brandName").text(data.groups[i].widgets[j].brandName);

    $("." + data.groups[i].name + " > .widgets-container > ." + data.groups[i].widgets[j].name + " > .widget-header > .widget-label > .row > .productName").text(data.groups[i].widgets[j].productName);

    var controlDiv;
    if (data.groups[i].widgets[j].controls[k].type === "SWITCH") {
      controlDiv = lightControl();
    } else if (data.groups[i].widgets[j].controls[k].type === "SLIDER") {
      controlDiv = brightnessControl();
    } else if (data.groups[i].widgets[j].controls[k].type === "PICKER") {
      controlDiv = colorControl();
    }

    controlDiv = $(controlDiv).addClass(data.groups[i].widgets[j].controls[k].name);

    $("." + data.groups[i].widgets[j].controls[k].name > ".control-name").text(data.groups[i].widgets[j].controls[k].name);

    $("." + data.groups[i].name + " > .widgets-container").append(widgetDiv);
    $(widgetDiv).append(controlDiv);
    $(".container-box").append(groupDiv);
  }
```

However, the elements are not getting appended as required from the JSON. Also, the labels for light/brightness/color control does not appear. Where am I going wrong?

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thank you.[image]

Comment: you are adding some classes with control names like Light Control. If you are going to access somewhere then it can create problem. So make sure you have class syntaxt like light-control

Comment: Provide us your wanted output `HTML` like screen shot.

Comment: @gitesh :I shall rectify that. Thank you. Any luck with the looping issue?

Comment: @JaydeepMor: Please check the question. There is an attached screenshot :)

Comment: Not screenshot want `HTML`.

Comment: you should use client framework like angularjs for complex ui :)

Comment: @GiteshPurbia : Please check : https://jsfiddle.net/inchrvndr/7efcqwdL/

Comment: @JaydeepMor: Its fixed. Please check https://jsfiddle.net/inchrvndr/7efcqwdL/

Comment: @IncharaRaveendra Great job :)

Answer (score 1):

here is the answer fiddle : [AnswerFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/inchrvndr/7efcqwdL/)

I fixed this issue by first creating DOM elements and then assigning/appending values to the DOM elements.

Earlier there was an issue because sometimes assigning of value would be attempted even before DOM element was created.

```
    controlDiv = $(controlDiv).addClass("row " + (data.groups[i].widgets[j].controls[k].name).replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase()).prepend("<div class='col s7 controlName'>" + data.groups[i].widgets[j].controls[k].name + "</div>");

    if (data.groups[i].widgets[j].controls[k].type === 'SWITCH') {
      $(controlDiv).append('<div class="col s5 switch"><label>OFF<input type= "checkbox"><span class="lever"></span>ON</label></div>')
    } else if (data.groups[i].widgets[j].controls[k].type === 'SLIDER') {
      $(controlDiv).append('<div class="col s5 center-align"><img src="images/brightness.png"></div><p class="col s7 range-field"><input type="range" min = "0" max = "100"/></p><div class="col s5 brightness-percentage center-align">60%</div>')
    } else if (data.groups[i].widgets[j].controls[k].type === 'PICKER') {
      $(controlDiv).append('<input class="col s2" type="color" name="favcolor" value="#ff0000"><div class="col s3 colorHexValue center-align">#ff0000</div>')

    } else if (data.groups[i].widgets[j].controls[k].type === 'GRAPH') {
      $(controlDiv).html("<img src='images/graph.png'>");
    } else if (data.groups[i].widgets[j].controls[k].type === 'DETECTOR') {
      $(controlDiv).html("<img src='images/motion.png'>")
    }


    widgetDiv.append(controlDiv);
    groupDiv.append(widgetDiv);
    $(".container-box").append(groupDiv);
```

Comment: i think your issue was at these lines :  $("." + data.groups[i].name + " > .widgets-container > ." + data.groups[i].widgets[j].name + " > .widget-header > .widget-label > .row > .brandName").text(data.groups[i].widgets[j].brandName);

Comment: where you tried to get element before they are append to dom